# Could Khan have used the Enterprise's prefix codes to lower its shields?

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan

In *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan*, Khan and his crew have hijacked the *Defiant* and have raised their shields. Fortunately, Kirk and company on the *Enterprise* have a way to disable them.

> Spock: Reliant's prefix number is one six three zero nine.
>
> Saavik: I don't understand.
>
> Kirk: You have to learn why things work on a starship.
>
> Spock: Each ship has its combination code.
>
> Kirk: To prevent an enemy do what we're attempting. Using our console to order Reliant to lower her shields.

Wouldn't this trick work both ways? What would prevent hijacked ships from disabling Starfleet ships in the same way?

If Khan knew about the prefix codes, and Kirk had raised his shields, couldn't Khan have used *Reliant*'s computers to look up the *Enterprise*'s prefix codes and disabled its shields?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've seen that - is Spock shown looking the prefix number up on the computer, or might he just have memorized it?

Comment: The whole point of the movie was that Khan was not experienced at space combat. He probably didn't even know the prefix code existed.

Comment: @RichS I get that Khan didn't know that it existed (we'll assume that he didn't learn about them during his study of the *Enterprise*'s technical schematics in "Space Seed". But if he did know abot them, wouldn't that be a pretty serious design flaw in the prefix codes? I mean, if a hijacked ship can look up the codes to disable a Starfleet-controlled ship, why bother having them?

Comment: @Thunderforge I have often wondered the same question about the prefix codes. Creating a code that allows other ships to control yours remotely is a huge security flaw!

Comment: @RichS but it's 5 numbers... The odds of guessing it by accident must be trillions and trillions to one :p

Comment: @JonClements Just 5 numbers. Just 1 more digit than a smartphone lockout code. Maybe the starship computers drop the internet connection after 3 failed attempts. :-b

Comment: One thing you have to remember, Kirk is an Admiral at that point. That means that he has authority not just on his own ship, but also on any ship in the fleet. It's likely that command codes wouldn't have been available to Khan, as there was no one with that authority on board the Reliant. The only other time they were used, Picard had been ordered by an Admiral to find a rogue starship, and could have presumably been given the codes for that ship as part of the mission.

Comment: @Jonathan Would you consider turning that into an answer? I was unaware that Picard had used it once, so more information about the circumstances about when they could be used may make a compelling answer.

Comment: @Jonathan wasn't that the transponder frequency? Or something similar - doesn't immediately ring a bell as anything like WoK.

Comment: @JonClements No, those were both the prefix codes. From the episode "The Wounded". More details in my answer below.

Comment: Let's not forget that Khan is an idiot despite whatever they try to portray him as. His "superior intellect" is implied since his actions on screen in basically every instance show him being defeated pretty quickly, both old and reboots. His character is one of my greatest disappointments in Star Trek

Comment: @JonClements I rewatched it last night. The Cardassians were originally asking just for the transponder code in order to track the Phoenix. When it looked like Phoenix was going to attack the freighter, Picard ordered Worf to send the nearest Cardassian warship the prefix codes (which Worf objects to, stating that they would have the ability to lower the Phoenix's shields).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing you have to remember, Kirk is an Admiral at that point. That means that he has authority not just on his own ship, but also on any ship in the fleet.

The only other time we've seen prefix codes used was during the TNG episode "The Wounded". Picard was ordered by Admiral Haden to track down the Phoenix when its captain went rogue and began attacking Cardassian ships. To my knowledge, it isn't explicitly stated how Picard has the Phoenix's code to give to the Cardassian ship.

Considering both instances involved a member of the admiralty, it's conceivable that this information is only available to members of the admiralty, or accessed on their authority. In which case, the Reliant wouldn't have had Enterprise's code, as no one on that ship would have had the authorization of a member of the admiralty.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree. If a ship is commandeered, you can't count on the next Starfleet ship it meets to have an admiral on board.  More likely there's a standard procedure: 1) Look up the target's prefix codes. (List may be restricted to command staff). 2) Change your own codes. 3) Fight the commandeered ship. 4) Transmit your new codes Starfleet in a Top Secret encoded message. (Step 4 can wait until the successful completion of Step 3.)

Comment: This wouldn't explain why Admiral Layton didn't give the Lakota the Defiant's prefix code in paradise lost.

Comment: If a ship is commandeered, any ship sent after it would most likely be given the command codes by whatever admiral gave the order, as Picard probably was by Admiral Haden. Otherwise, why didn't Maxwell use his command authority to take control of the Enterprise in The Wounded? The first rule of security is separation of control. If you have access to A, you aren't also given control over B. A captain wouldn't have their own codes, and an Admiral wouldn't be given their own ship (Kirk being an unusual situation).

Comment: @Servitor, as shown in TWOK, the trick would only work against a crew who wouldn't expect it to happen, otherwise they just flick a switch. Maxwell got blindsided by it because he didn't expect the Cardassians to know what code to transmit, but even then, as demonstrated a few seconds later, he was back in the battle and won easily. His Ops officer probably knew where the switch was.

Answer (score 12):

From the [scene in question](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie2.html):

> JOACHIM: Sir! Our shields are dropping!
>
> KHAN: Raise them.
>
> JOACHIM: I can't!
>
> KHAN: Where's the override? The override?

Khan, despite his inexperience, understood what was happening, and knew there was a countermeasure available under the circumstances: a manual override. He simply didn't know where the relevant controls were. Had he or his crew attempted this maneuver first instead of Kirk, it presumably would have failed, as the *Enterprise* crew would have been more thoroughly trained with the relevant controls.

Presumably, after this scene, Spock or Scott acted off-camera to prevent Khan from trying the same trick, likely by changing the prefix codes.

Comment: Additionally, *Enterprise* was effectively unshielded for the balance of the movie, so it wasn't an issue.

Comment: There's also the possibility that while Khan and Co. had manual control of the ship that they didn't have necessary access to the ship's library computer to get the codes (there's no evidence of that of course but just maybe...)

Comment: (mind you - given Star Fleet's amazing advances in security - I wouldn't be surprised if there was a bright red folder in front of Khan with "Top Secret Access Codes for remote controlling Star Fleet vessels" written on it that now and then shouted "I'm top secret - pretend I'm not here!")

Comment: And therein lies the rest of the answer. If used against a federation-controlled ship it's an annoyance. If used against a commandeered one it's probably a loss.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entirely more plausible explanation that is nevertheless, as far as I know, non-canon:

The prefix code is *not* meant for doing  this, and what Kirk briefly refers to is actually quite a complex hack that he has been sitting on for some time - Kirk has been knowledgeable in computer hacking ever since his academy days - and must also have previously discussed with Spock in order for Spock to instantly understand his shorthand. Had Kirk ever disclosed the possibility of using this hack to Starfleet, it would have patched the hole. It's likely he's not even certain it will work, which is belied by his dialog in the movie itself.

When he says to Saavik

> You have to learn why things work on a starship

He's actually flexing his hacker smugness, and it is not a direct pearl of wisdom to educate the cadet - it is *not* that simple, and once what he has just done is learned of it will probably never be possible again.*

*except for the lazy callback in *The Next Generation*.

Answer (score -1):

Khan demanded Kirk hand over all data related to the Genesis project. Receiving said data was what created a back door into the system, which is why Reliant's shields went down the moment they made the transfer.